# How to print out Gremlin pipe / traversal results

Tags: groovy, gremlin

I have the code below in a file named `traversal.groovy` (which I call from the command line with `gremlin -e traversal.groovy`):

```
// Begin traversal.groovy //

g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
v = g.v(1)

println v.outE.inV.name

// End traversal.groovy //
```

As you can see, it's very basic; but the output is not what I'm looking for.  The output is

```
[StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe, InVertexPipe, PropertyPipe(name)]
```

When I run the same code in the gremlin command line, I get what I'm looking for...

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> v = g.v(1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> v.outE.inV.name
==>vadas
==>josh
==>lop
```

So, how do I access the information that I want that's somehow tucked away in `[StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe, InVertexPipe, PropertyPipe(name)]`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [stephen mallette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831717/stephen-mallette) for pointing me in the right direction. To simply print out the "name" property of each vertex in my traversal above, we can use [sideEffect](http://gremlindocs.com/#side-effect/sideeffect) and [iterate](http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-iterate). The resulting code would look as follows:

```
// Begin traversal.groovy //

g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
v = g.v(1)

v.outE.inV.sideEffect{println it.name}.iterate()

// End traversal.groovy //
```

and the output would be:

```
vadas
josh
lop
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely just need to iterate your pipeline:

http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-next

```
println v.outE.inV.name.next()
```

Comment: That's possibly something I could work with, but I'd have to loop that I would think, because that only returns `vadas`. I'm curious why `println v.outE.inV.name.iterate()` doesn't work?

Comment: Wasn't clear to me what you were trying to do.  next() only pops the first item out of the pipeline.  and iterate() just blows through the pipeline to out side-effects.  so if your goal is just to println everything in the pipeline, just do v.outE.inV.name.sideEffect{println it}.iterate().  if your next step is to later do something with the names, pipe them into a list with something like l=[];v.outE.inV.name.fill(l);l.each{println it}; Remember, the gremlin repl, iterates your pipelines for you so when you use a script you have to think a little differently.