# Print out Gremlin 3.1.1 Results in Groovy Without Gremlin Console

Tags: groovy, gremlin

I'm trying to print out results from a Gremlin traversal. This is similar to this question, but different to this question:

[How to print out Gremlin pipe / traversal results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508599/how-to-print-out-gremlin-pipe-traversal-results)

I'm trying to do this without the Gremlin console. Below is a code example, but nothing is produced with the sideEffect()

```
@Grab('org.apache.tinkerpop:tinkergraph-gremlin:3.1.1-incubating')
@Grab('org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-core:3.1.1-incubating')

import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory;

Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
def g = graph.traversal();
println(g.V(1).out('name').toString());
g.V(1).out('name').sideEffect{println it.name}.iterate();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a picture of the modern graph you are using
[image: TinkerPop Modern]

You can see that vertex 1 is the Marko node, and it has three out-going edges:

```
vertex1 --created--> vertex3
vertex1 --knows--> vertex2
vertex1 --knows--> vertex4
```

In Gremlin, these can be expressed like using [vertex steps](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#vertex-steps):

```
g.V(1).out('created').next()
g.V(1).outE('knows').inV().toList()
```

Based on your code, it looks like maybe you want to get the [vertex property](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#vertex-properties) `name` on the adjacent vertices. In this case, leave out the edge labels, and the get the vertex property value:

```
g.V(1).out().values('name').sideEffect{println it}.iterate()
```

FYI, the link you referenced is showing TinkerPop2 code. You should refer to the [TinkerPop 3.1.1-incubating documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#intro).